# Find all reference on all projects in solution

Tags: visual-studio, find-all-references

My solution contains multiple projects (say P1, P2). In project dependencies, I set P2 to depend on P1, so P2 uses some classes in P1. When I do a Find All References on a class/method of P1, the result shows only the occurences in P1; not the occurences used in P2. Is there a way to have Find All References work on the entire solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Project -> Project Dependencies is only for describing additional non-link related dependencies.  To specify a link dependency for unmanaged code use:

Project -> Properties -> Common Properties -> Framework and References -> References -> Add New Reference... -> Projects

and for managed code use:

Project -> Add Reference -> Projects

If this is set up correctly Visual Studio should be able to find inter-project references.

Comment: Thanks, I have been using Project -> Add Reference -> Browse. That's why it didn't work for me.

Comment: Re. "Project -> Add Reference -> Projects": Doesn't that already have to be setup correctly for the Project to even compile?  Mine is, and it's still not finding References outside the Project containing the Definition.

Re. "Project -> Properties -> Common Properties ->...": I'm not seeing a "Common Properties" option under "Project -> Properties" (in at least VS Pro 2015 v14.0.25421.03 Update 3) for C# Windows Application.